# Number of video feeds in a single chrome window

Tags: webrtc

I am taking RTSP feed from IP Cameras and showing it using WebRTC Endpoint on Chrome. 
I want to show multiple feeds in a single chrome browser like a video wall. 
My question is, how many such feeds can be shown using a single chrome window and how can it be scaled on the chrome end?

Comment: Zero, since webrtc does not support RTSP as far as I know.

Comment: Wrong!! Check this: http://www.kurento.org/blog/interoperating-webrtc-and-ip-cameras. I am already showing the feeds from 5 IP Cameras in Chrome. I just want to know how many such feeds can be shown in a single Chrome window.

Comment: You're using a media gateway? Then that's *because webrtc doesn't support RTSP*. AFAIK there's no theoretical limit in WebRTC here. You should tag your question with `kurento` if you're looking for people with experience with that particular configuration and any limitations it may have. It's likely to vary based on many factors, not the least network bandwith. I don't see a general programming question here. Why don't you try with more cameras and report back?